# Announcement Channel for Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote a code for creating a text channel and a voice channel in Discord.py rewrite. Now I wanted to to create an announcement Channel with my bot but there is no command for that in the documentation. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of requirements to creating an `announcement channel` (also known as a `news channel`), so you can't just make them from code. They're not meant to be freely created in masses, so that's why you're supposed to make them manually. To be more specific:

> Who can make them?
> You must have a **dev license** (https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/APPLICATION-ID-GOES-HERE/developer-license, **app must be part of a team and costs $25**), be a **verified server** or be a **partnered server**.

Comment: You can make announcement channels if your discord server is a community server.